# Change order to all records linq to Sql c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have three tables.

In **first** table I have `articleId`, `articleName` ..., in **second** table `storeId`, `storeName`, `storeLocation`, `maxNumOfArticles`... in **third** table `articleId`, `storeId` and `order`.

I want for example in first store to add new article. what

I need to do is to increment the order to all articles in the store, so the new article would have order 1.

For example in store A `maxNumOfArticles = 5`, when I insert new article, article with num 5 will be deleted , article with order 4, now will be with order 5, article with order 3 will have order 4..... and the new article will have order 1.

Comment: why you want to change the Order? try to read top 5 Ordered descending By Date Or ID

Comment: and what have you tried? Can you show the code?

Comment: First: it looks like a design issue. Why should a record which has foreign key be deleted when a new record is inserted. Second: is the number which you use primary key with increment? Is the number stored in `articleId`? I would prefer to retrieve the records ordered by articleId desc.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz This is a pretty common pattern for clearing out old data. The problem is that he wants to manually manage the `order` column instead of just letting the database do it for him.

Answer (score 2):

That's not something LINQ to SQL is meant to do. First, you need a view that automatically numbers your articles by store:

```
CREATE VIEW ArticleStoreView AS
SELECT a.articleId ,
       a.articleName ,
       a.publicationDate,
       asm.storeId ,
       s.storeName ,
       s.maxNumOfArticles,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY asm.storeId ORDER BY publicationDate DESC  ) AS [Order]
        FROM dbo.Article a INNER JOIN dbo.ArticleStoreMap asm  ON asm.articleId = a.articleId
INNER JOIN dbo.Store s ON s.storeId = asm.storeId
```

This will ensure that your order is always correct.

---

To get just the relevant articles, you can write this query:

```
SELECT  asv.articleId ,
        asv.articleName ,
        asv.publicationDate ,
        asv.storeId ,
        asv.storeName ,
        asv.maxNumOfArticles ,
        asv.[Order]
FROM    dbo.ArticleStoreView asv
WHERE   asv.[Order] <= asv.maxNumOfArticles
ORDER BY asv.publicationDate DESC
```

To delete the old article/store maps:

```
DELETE  dbo.ArticleStoreMap
FROM    dbo.ArticleStoreMap asm
        INNER JOIN dbo.ArticleStoreView asv ON asv.articleId = asm.articleId
                                               AND asv.storeId = asm.storeId
WHERE   asv.[Order] > asv.maxNumOfArticles
```

To delete the old articles that are no longer mapped

```
DELETE dbo.Article
FROM dbo.Article a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.ArticleStoreMap asm WHERE asm.articleId = a.articleId)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to read Top 5 ordered in descending take look at this code :

```
myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.InsertDate).Take(5);
```